# How is the sequence $x_{n+1} = \frac{(x_n)^{2} + 5}{ 6}$ going to converge to 1

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Having some trouble understanding that if $x_{1} = 4$ and the sequence where n is defined as $x_{n+1} = \frac{(x_n)^{2} + 5}{ 6}$ how is it going to converge to 1.

I have solved using the L as limit and using the quadratic i get two possibilites that are 5, or 1.

Comment: Do you know how to use the theorem on bounded monotonic sequences? Has that been explained to you? Using it you can show that the limit exists. Only then can you find the limit $L$ (and discard the one that does not fit the monotonicity).

Comment: Here you should try to show that the sequence is decreasing, and bounded from below by $1$.

Comment: Jyrki gave one way of doing this that works. I'm going to suggest a different way (and trying both of them is probably not bad). Can you find an explicit function $f(x)$ where $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x)=0$ such that $x_n < 1+ f(n)$? If you can do this (essentially showing explicitly that each step puts you much closer to 6 than the previous step), then you can then take that limit.

Answer (score 3):

By induction, $1< x_n\le 4$ for all $n$. Indeed, this is true for $n=1$, and if $1< x_n\le 4$, then $1< x_n^2\le 16$ and so $x_{n+1}=\frac{x_n^2+5}{6}$ is $> \frac{1+5}6=1$ and $\le \frac{16+5}6<4$.

With these bounds in mind, we have
$$x_{n+1}-x_n=\frac{x_n^2-6x_n+5}6=\frac{(x_n-1)(x_n-5)}6<0$$
because the first factor in the numerator is positive and the second is negative.

So $\{x_n\}_n$ is bounded and strictly decreasing, hence convergent. You already found out that the only possible limits are $1$ and $5$. However, $5$ can be excluded according to the above observations.

Answer (score 2):

You may reason as follows:

- Set $f(x) = \frac{x^2+5}{6}$.
- $\Rightarrow f(1) = 1, f(5) = 5$ and for any $a \in (1,5)$ you have $f(a) \in (1,5)$.
- $f''(x) = \frac{1}{3} > 0$, so $f$ is strictly convex.
- $\Rightarrow$ the secant through $(1,1)$ and $(5,5)$ lies above the graph of $f$:
  $$f(a) < a \mbox{ for any } a \in (1,5) \Rightarrow (x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mbox{ is decreasing.}$$
  It follows from your calculation that $L=1$ must be the limit (and cannot be $5$).

Comment: It also helps to show that $f'(x)=\frac{x}{3}$ is $f'(1)=\frac13<1$, which makes it a convergent fixed point, while $f'(5)=\frac53>1$, which means it is a divergent fixed point.

Answer (score 0):

Since
$$
x_{n+1}=\frac{x_n^2+5}6\tag1
$$
we have
$$
x_{n+2}-x_{n+1}=\frac{x_{n+1}^2-x_n^2}6=(x_{n+1}-x_n)\,\frac{x_{n+1}+x_n}6\tag2
$$
This is a contraction when $\left|\frac{x_{n+1}+x_n}6\right|\lt1$. That is.
$$
-1\lt\frac{(x_n+3)^2-4}{36}\lt1\tag3
$$
Inequality $(3)$ is satisfied when
$$
-3-2\sqrt{10}\lt x_n\lt-3+2\sqrt{10}\tag4
$$
$x_1=4$ is outside the range specified in $(4)$.